# mongod: command not found on aws c9

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, c9.io

I have been trying to start the mongoDB server after following all the instructions on the c9 website but nothing seems to work.
This is what I'm getting

```
ec2-user:~ $ ls
data  environment  mongod
ec2-user:~ $ ./mongod
./mongod: line 1: mongod: command not found
ec2-user:~ $
```

ls -al

```
total 76
drwx------   9 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 22 22:38 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root     4096 Oct 24 18:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 22 22:38 .aws
-rw-------   1 ec2-user ec2-user 5469 Dec 22 22:40 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 ec2-user ec2-user   18 Aug 15  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--   1 ec2-user ec2-user  218 Oct 24 18:43 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 ec2-user ec2-user 1410 Dec 19 16:29 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root      142 Dec 19 16:29 .bashr_profile
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ec2-user ec2-user    7 Oct 24 18:57 .c9 -> /opt/c9
drwxrwxr-x   2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 22 09:42 data
drwxr-xr-x   8 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 22 13:10 environment
-rw-rw-r--   1 ec2-user ec2-user   31 Dec 22 22:38 .gitconfig
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ec2-user ec2-user   58 Dec 22 14:36 mongod
-rw-------   1 ec2-user ec2-user   41 Dec 20 08:50 .node_repl_history
drwxrwxr-x 126 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 22 14:17 .npm
drwxrwxr-x   5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Oct 24 18:43 .nvm
drwxrw----   3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Oct 24 18:43 .pki
drwx------   2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec  5 12:21 .ssh
-rw-------   1 ec2-user ec2-user 3711 Dec  5 12:22 .viminfo

which mongo


 /usr/bin/which: no mongo in (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

Comment: please provide us the result of `ls -al` and try the following command `which mongo` `which mongod` and paste the result

Comment: I have added the results in the question

Comment: please format the output correctly, this is akward

Comment: and please add the tutorial you followed

Comment: https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mongodb/1717 this where I got the step to follow

Comment: I have formatted it correctly now

Comment: it looks like your `mongod` binary was not downloaded correctly. Did `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` run correctly without errors?

Comment: `ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo: apt-get: command not found
ec2-user:~/environment $ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1039 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do
ec2-user:~/environment $`

Comment: See this is what I get whenever and when I ran `yum info mongodb` I get a strange long message about mongodb being on the system

Comment: This the notice I get when I try to use `apt-get` : On Amazon Linux use `yum ` instead of `apt-get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tutorial you are following is for Ubuntu Linux. It looks like you have a Centos Linux. Try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-7